# Insert variable inside a check_call / check_output in python 2.7?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, beeline

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to make a mini software where i read a csv, insert it into a variable and then give this variable to a check_call function.
The CSV is a list of databases:

```
cat test_db.csv

andreadb
billing
fabiodb
```

And this is what i wrote right now:

```
from subprocess import *
import csv

#Load the CSV inside the variable data
with open('test_db.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
     data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
#For loop that per each database it shows me the tables and the output saved into risultato.txt
for line in data:
        database = line
        check_call[("beeline", "-e", "\"SHOW TABLES FROM \"", database, ";" , ">>" , "risultato.txt")]
```

When i execute it i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_query.py", line 10, in <module>
    check_call[("beeline", "-e", "\"SHOW TABLES FROM \"", database, ";")]
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm relatively new to python and this is my first project, so any help would be great.
If i didn't explained correctly something, please tell me and i'll edit the post.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback error, and implementation of `check_call` function

Comment: Edited and added, thanks!

Comment: _Relatively new to Python_ - Don't use Python2.7, by the way. Also, PySpark can do all this. You shouldn't need beeline

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer, but i must use it because the server who has hdfs only has python 2.7.5, and i can't use libraries for security reasons.
I wishi i could use either PySpark or PyHive or even Pandas, but it's not possible sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped the function call. It should be

```
check_call(["beeline", "-e", "\"SHOW TABLES FROM \"", database, ";" , ">>" , "risultato.txt"])
```

The `(` was placed after `[` in your question. It should be `(` first followed by a list of commands and params.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tinkering i found a way to concatenate the variable in this check_call:

```
for line in data:
        i=0
        database=str(line[i])
        check_call(["beeline -e \"SHOW TABLES FROM "+database+"\" >> risultato.txt"])
        i+=i
```

After execution it produces the correct output after saving it in risultato.txt:

```
+-----------+
| tab_name  |
+-----------+
| result    |
| results   |
+-----------+
+------------------------------------+
|              tab_name              |
+------------------------------------+
| tab_example_1                      |
| tab_example_2                      |
+------------------------------------+
+---------------------------------------+
|               tab_name                |
+---------------------------------------+
| tab_example_3                         |
| tab_example_4                         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can do `for i, line in enumerate(data)` to get a counter and the value